# How to save as Image From Stream which is send in retrofit2 to wcf web service

Tags: c#, android, web-services, wcf, retrofit2

I am sending a image file to wcf web service using retrofit, on saving side of wcf web service i am unable to save the stream file.

In android i creating like

```
//ApiInterface.class
@Multipart
@POST("RestService/json/PostUploadFile/")
Call<UploadFileResponse> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

service call be like

```
File file = new File(assets.get(0).getPath());
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

// MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imageData", file.getName(), requestFile);

//api call method
callUploadFile(part, this);

private void callUploadFile(MultipartBody.Part part,
                               MainInteractor.OnFinishedListener listenerP) {
            final MainInteractor.OnFinishedListener listener = listenerP;

            HashMap<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
            headerMap.put("SessionID", "");
            headerMap.put("UserName", "");
            OkHttpClient httpClient = ConnectToService.newInstance().addHeaders(getContext(), headerMap);

            ApiInterface apiService =
                    ConnectToService.newInstance()
                            .getClient(httpClient).create(ApiInterface.class);

            Call<UploadFileResponse> call = apiService.uploadFile(part);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadFileResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<UploadFileResponse> call, Response<UploadFileResponse> response) {
                    onFinished(response.body().getResult());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<UploadFileResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    if (t.getLocalizedMessage() != null) {
                        onFinishedFailure(t.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

In wcf webservice i am getting data in message but when i save i get argument exception error.[image: Getting Data in message] [image: Getting error when i save]

**EDITED: Below code works**

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(assets.get(finalX).getPath());
                        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 480, 480, true);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
                        byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
                        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"), byteArray);
                        callUploadFile(body, "File_" + finalX, MainFragment.this);
```

calling service method

```
private void callUploadFile(RequestBody body, String fileName,
                           MainInteractor.OnFinishedListener listenerP) {
        final MainInteractor.OnFinishedListener listener = listenerP;

        HashMap<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
        headerMap.put("SessionID", "");
        headerMap.put("UserName", "");
        headerMap.put("FileName", fileName);
        OkHttpClient httpClient = ConnectToService.newInstance().addHeaders(getContext(), headerMap);

        ApiInterface apiService =
                ConnectToService.newInstance()
                        .getClient(httpClient).create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<UploadFileResponse> call = apiService.uploadFile(body);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadFileResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UploadFileResponse> call, Response<UploadFileResponse> response) {
                if (response != null && response.body() != null) {
                    onFinished(response.body().getResult());
                } else {
                    if (response.message() != null) {
                        onFinishedFailure(response.message());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UploadFileResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                if (t.getLocalizedMessage() != null) {
                    onFinishedFailure(t.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

In wcf service

```
public string uploadFile(Stream imageData)
        {
            string fileName = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers.Get("fileName");
            string fileFullPath = "D:\\Share\\srinidhi\\Temp_" + fileName + ".Jpeg";

            Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageData);
            img.Save(fileFullPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            return "success";
        }
```

In api call

```
@POST("RestService/json/PostUploadFile/")
    Call<UploadFileResponse> uploadFile(@Body RequestBody bytes);
```

Comment: Looks like the image is base64 encoded

Comment: @TheGeneral could you please tell the code how to save, really i dont know how to save, i searched a lot but nothing works...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your stream is submitted by the form-data, which means that the stream contains some unnecessary data, such as the other data in the submitted form-data. One thing must be noted that WCF doesn’t support the form-data by default, we generally convert the data to the complete file data by using the third-party library, **MultipartParser**.
Here is the download page.
http://antscode.blogspot.com/2009/11/parsing-multipart-form-data-in-wcf.html
Under this circumstance, please use the below code segments to save the image.

```
public async Task UploadStream(Stream stream)
        {
            //the third-party library.
            MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(stream);

            if (parser.Success)
            {
                //absolute filename, extension included.
                var filename = parser.Filename;
                var filetype = parser.ContentType;
                var ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                using (var file = File.Create(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Uploads"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() +ext)))
                {
                    await file.WriteAsync(parser.FileContents, 0, parser.FileContents.Length);
                }
            }
}
```

If the stream is the complete binary file, please consider the below code (we use the HTTP header to save the file extension since WCF doesn’t allow to contain another parameter in the method signature).

```
public async Task UploadStream(Stream stream)
        {
            var context = WebOperationContext.Current;
            string filename = context.IncomingRequest.Headers["filename"].ToString();
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
            using (stream)
            {
                //save the image under the Uploads folder on the server-side(root directory).
                using (var file = File.Create(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Uploads"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext)))
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(file);
                }
            }
        }
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: i already tried MultipartParser that to cause invalid argument exception only so change to "application/octet-stream" and now it is worked. thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, it's nice in that code snippets.